# a constant in dependent base class make out-of-line definition not matched?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, crtp

```cpp
template<template<typename, size_t>class V, typename, size_t N>
struct X{
    static constexpr size_t stride = N;
};

template<typename Num, size_t N>
struct Y;
template<typename Num>
struct Y<Num, 3> : protected X<Y, Num, 3>{
    using X<Y, Num, 3>::stride;

    Y<Num, stride> foo(Num angle, Y<Num, stride> axis) const;
};
```

I try to provide a definition for `foo` like:

1.

```cpp
template<typename Num>
Y<Num, 3> Y<Num, 3>::foo(Num angle, Y<Num, 3> axis) const{};
```

2. 

```cpp
template<typename Num>
Y<Num, Y<Num, 3>::stride> Y<Num, 3>::foo(Num angle, Y<Num, Y<Num, 3>::stride> axis) const{};
```

3. 

```cpp
template<typename Num>
Y<Num, X<Y, Num, 3>::stride> Y<Num, 3>::foo(Num angle, Y<Num, X<Y, Num, 3>::stride> axis) const{};
```

but none of them is accepted by compilers *(clang, msvc, and gcc 7.5-)*. *(why gcc 8.1+ works?)*

but if I define `stride` at `Y` like `static constexpr size_t stride = X<Y, Num, 3>::stride`, **1** and **2** work.

or if `X` is not a class template, they work as well.

what's the reason? a mistake declared by standard or just a compiler bug? and how to work at the `using X::stride` situation?

code: https://godbolt.org/z/asn8rj.

Comment: I'm not gonna interfere with your pursuit of a normative answer, but I would point out that it's fairly easy to work around the problem. Adding an alias `using foo_res = Y<Num, stride>;` and providing the out of line definition as `auto Y<Num, 3>::foo(Num, Y::foo_res) const -> Y::foo_res {}` appeases all the compilers.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica oh, it's a good idea. just `using A3<T> = Y<T, 3>` will solve it. I think it's equivalent to redefining something to make them to be the same `stride`. anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Remember that template (`X`) could be specialized, so option 1 is clearly wrong.

Comment: Option 2/3 seems more promising, but`stride` is not directly from Y or from X (remember that X might be specialized and we are in partial specialization). I try trailing return type [as option 4](https://godbolt.org/z/YGzWc3) but clang still dislike it :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, ominously, [CWG2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2), a lack of specification in the standard whose filing date has literally been forgotten.  That said, your option #2 seems clearly the correct choice, since it names the same *using-declaration* as the declaration in the class.

Comment: the match rule is even unspecified? amazing.