# Template class type alias failing substitution in member declaration

Tags: c++, class, templates, alias, declaration

Assume you have a templated `class` like this:

```cpp
template <typename type>
class Object {
  using length_t = unsigned int;
  
  template <length_t length>
  void put(type (&)[length]);
};
```

and you declared a `put(...)` method in it like so.
How do you go about declaring that `put(...)` method outside the `class`?

1. Here's one approach someone might take:

   ```cpp
   /* ERROR: Doesn't match any declarations(?) */
   template <typename type>
   template <typename Object<type>::length_t length>
   void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length]) {}
   ```

   but this leads to a peculiar error

   ```
   error: no declaration matches 'void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length])'

   note: candidate is: 
     template <class type>
     template <unsigned int length>
     void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length])
   ```
2. Here's another way to declare the `put(...)` method such that it works:

   ```cpp
   /* SUCCESS: But `length_t` alias isn't used */
   template <typename type>
   template <unsigned int length>
   void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length]) {}
   ```

   but the `length_t` type alias defined in the `class` isn't used.

How does one get the first definition to work so as to keep the use of the `class`'s features (like type aliases) consistent across its declaration & definitions, or is the second definition the only solution here?

Comment: So there may be a few design / style choices with the code examples that's uncommon or unaccepted with modern C++ code but I'd like to disclaim that the question posed still remains inspite of any criticisms to how the code looks or what its function is.

Comment: That's fine. You can add that disclaimer to the question itself though, instead of as a comment.

Comment: is `lenght_t` as a type trait instead of member alias an option? I suppose not and you want no changes on the declaration of the class

Comment: @cigien Thank you. I believe the disclaimer should stay here for now as it is less related to the question than how people may answer or view it

Comment: how ppl answer or view it is related to how they answer ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 `length_t` is a dummy type used in the example to denote that the `Object` class has a type alias it uses in the `put(...)` member function

Comment: I know, thats what I read in the question. But would it be acceptable to have `lenght_t` not as member but as a type trait instead? Instead of `Object<T>::lenght_t` it would be something along the line of `length_t<T>` or `length_t<Object<T>>`

Comment: what I am unsure about is whether you dislike the second solution only because you have to resort to `unsigned int` explicitly, or whether there are other reasons you want to have the first

Comment: @idclev463035818 Firstly, would redefining `length_t` from a type alias to a type trait be more (or less) syntactically clear and functional (if so, how)? Secondly, the second solution can be deferred to but 'd like to see if the first approach can be resolved so as to keep the code (a bit more) consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a compiler bug, or further more, a defect in standard.

your code actually has NO problem, and is accepted by *MSVC*. and if you put the definition inside the class, no compiler will think it's ill-formed.

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443239/a-constant-in-dependent-base-class-make-out-of-line-definition-not-matched) that is similar to this. and I get the result that, *[CWG2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2)*, the ancient issue that nobody knows when it's posted, is still **drafting**, which means the match rule of out-of-definition is even **unspecified**. these weird mismatches are because of the different implementations of compilers.

and then, for how to avoid this problem, firstly you can put the definition inside the class. and if it depends on something defined behind the class definition and can not be defined inside, you can:

1. **make it independent**: let `using length_t = unsigned int;` outside.
2. **make it deducible when declaring**: compilers may not know if `typename Object<type>::length_t` and `length_t` (inside the class) are the same type, although `typename Object<type>::length_t` is not needed to be deducible. because at the declaring moment, compiler can not ensure if `Object<type>` is specified and make `length_t` mismatched, in my mind. so as what @idclev 463035818 said, `template<...> using length_t = unsigned int;` will make compiler easier to match this definition.

Answer (score 2):

> How does one get the first definition to work so as to keep the use of the class's features (like type aliases) consistent across its declaration & definitions,

I have to admit that I don't understand the error and I don't know how to fix it by changing the definition only. The error message is rather confusing (you should include it in the question).

> ... or is the second definition the only solution here?

No, it is not. If you are fine with having `length_t` not as member then this might point you in the right direction:

```
template <template<typename> typename T>
struct length { using type = int; };

template <template<typename> typename T>
using length_t = typename length<T>::type;


template <typename> struct Object;
template <> struct length<Object> { using type = unsigned int; };

template <typename type>
class Object {
  //using length_t = unsigned int;
  
  template <length_t<Object> length>
  void put(type (&)[length]);
};

template <typename type>
template <length_t<Object> length>
void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length]) {}
```

`length` is a "template trait" (not sure if this term actually exists). Instead of having `length_t` as member of `Object` you need to provide a specialization for `length<Object>` (and that needs a forward declaration of `Object`). The `int` base case is only for illustration. And if you like you can still add a member to `Object` to alias `length_t<Object>`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cocMW7)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time thus far but a few things: "The error message is rather confusing (you should include it in the question)", I believe 've already done as suggested (unless there's a misunderstanding) because the (actual) compiler error from trying the first attempt is exactly the same as the one expressed in the question (given some pedantic details like `<template-parameter-1-1>` are redacted).

Comment: Your solution is very well done (and appreciated) but there is a third attempt to the same effect of not having the `length_t` alias be a member of the `Object` class: https://godbolt.org/z/ba7Par

Comment: @Lapys on a second thought I think you dont need to change the defition to use the trait. Your solution is moot because then the problem doesnt exist in the fist place. The premise of the question is that `legnth_t` depends on `Object` otherwise there is no problem

Comment: @Lapys the complete error mesage is more than that. My compiler gives a good hint on a candidate (and thats the interesting and confusing part) https://godbolt.org/z/59PPKE

Comment: @Lapys in different words: please include the complete compiler error message in the question ;)

Comment: Sure sure ‍♂️. You're right, the full error message helps add more context to the problem. Any ideas why the compiler doesn't deduce `typename Object<...>::length_t` to an `unsigned int` when looking for declaration matches? I'd assumed it was a bug because this behavior seems to be exclusive to template `class`es 

Comment: Note that this unfortunately doesn't work with clang. I was attempting the same approach but can't find a way for clang to compile it.

Comment: @Darhuuk looks fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/K4Efoc What version?

Comment: @idclev463035818 My attempt was slightly different. Basically I was trying this: https://godbolt.org/z/od7oG3. I.e. not enforcing `length`'s parameter type to take a parameter itself.

Comment: @Darhuuk seems to be the same effect as with the original code. You cant use `type` in the second template declaration. Though `lenght_t` does not depend on `type` so my "template trait" fixed it

Comment: @Darhuuk no its something else, clang has no problem with this: https://godbolt.org/z/YrbE5o. Interesting...

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yeah, I don't understand what's going on here. Maybe a bug in clang?

Comment: @Darhuuk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600329/bartype-x-definition-does-not-match-bartype-x-declaration