# bar(type (&)[x]) definition does not match bar(type (&)[x]) declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

This is a follow up of [Template class type alias failing substitution in member declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64598755/4117728)

Consider this code:

```
// A
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    using type = unsigned;
   
    template <type x>
    void bar(type (&)[x]);
};
    
template <typename T>
template <typename foo<T>::type x>
void foo<T>::bar(type (&)[x]){}
```

[gcc emits the following error:](https://godbolt.org/z/vvEfnx)

```
<source>:13:6: error: no declaration matches 'void foo<T>::bar(foo<T>::type (&)[x])'
   13 | void foo<T>::bar(type (&)[x]){}
      |      ^~~~~~
<source>:8:10: note: candidate is: 'template<class T> template<unsigned int x> void foo<T>::bar(foo<T>::type (&)[x])'
    8 |     void bar(type (&)[x]);
      |          ^~~
<source>:4:8: note: 'struct foo<T>' defined here
    4 | struct foo {
      |        ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

[clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Kx6s5q):

```
<source>:13:14: error: out-of-line definition of 'bar' does not match any declaration in 'foo<T>'
void foo<T>::bar(type (&)[x]){}
             ^~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

When I remove what is identical in the erroneous definition and the candidate I get this:

```
// B
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    using type = unsigned;

    template <type x>
    void bar();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename foo<T>::type x>
void foo<T>::bar(){}
```

This compiles fine ([gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/1beTqW) / [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Yo9qoz))

An attempt to answer the original question (by Darhuuk, slightly modified) was this:

```
// C
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct length { using type = unsigned int; };    
template <typename T> using length_t = typename length<T>::type;

template <typename type>
class Object {
  template <length_t<Object<type>> length>
  void put(type (&)[length]);
};

template <typename type>
template <length_t<Object<type>> length>
void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length]) {}

int main() {}
```

Clang seems to have similar problems as with the original code and [emits the error](https://godbolt.org/z/Wj5Yr6):

```
<source>:15:20: error: out-of-line definition of 'put' does not match any declaration in 'Object<type>'
void Object<type>::put(type (&)[length]) {}
                   ^~~
1 error generated.
```

while [gcc compiles it without complaints](https://godbolt.org/z/9MGd7j).

Who is right about `C`? Is it a bug in clang or is gcc being lax?

Why does `A` not compile while `B` does?

Comment: duplicate is a slightly different case, though after reading the article linked in the duplicates answer I believe that it actually is the same issue

Answer (score 1):

as I mentioned in 
[Template class type alias failing substitution in member declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598755/template-class-type-alias-failing-substitution-in-member-declaration?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> *[CWG2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2)*, the ancient issue that nobody knows when it's posted, is still **drafting**, which means the match rule of out-of-definition is even **unspecified**. these weird mismatches are because of the different implementations of compilers.